# Plotting the condorcet jury theorem

Tags: plotting, functions, syntax

I am trying to create a simple plot of the condorcet jury theorem:

[image: Condorcet jury theorem formula]

The function is:

```
F[n_,i_,p_]:=((n!)/((n-i)!*i!))*((p^i) *(1-p)^(n-i))
```

embedded in a sum from `i` to `n`:

```
P[n_,i_]:=Sum[  F,{i,n}]
```

Then I create a Table with all the values for `N=1-100`, and `p=0.1-0.9`

```
B=Table[F[n,i,p],{n,1,100,10},{i,1},{p,0.1,0.9,0.1}]
```

Then I try to plot it:

```
ListPlot[B]
```

but the plot is empty.

What am I missing?

Comment: Do not use "N". use "n" instead

Comment: thanks I changed it to "n". but the plot is still empty

Comment: Try `ListPlot[Flatten@B]`

Comment: Please describe what the desired plot should look like.  Do you want a plot of `p` vs. `F` for each value of `n`?  (And I don't see why `P[n_,i_]:=Sum[  F,{i,n}]` is included in the question.)  In any event you'll need to follow @J42161217 's advice with the use of `Flatten`.  Take a look at `B` and see that it isn't in the form that `ListPlot` expects.  Maybe:  `B = Flatten[
  Table[{p, F[n, i, p]}, {n, 1, 100, 10}, {i, 1}, {p, 0.1, 0.9, 0.1}],
   1]; ListPlot[B, Joined -> True, PlotLegends -> Table[n, {n, 1, 100, 10}]]`.

Comment: This works. thank you both

Answer (score 2):

You may use [`DiscretePlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DiscretePlot.html).  Note that your functions should not begin with capital letters unless in a package.

With `F` as defined in OP and

```
ClearAll[P]
P[n_Integer, p_] := Sum[F[n, i, p], {i, n}]
```

Then for some `p`, say 0.3, and some `n`, say 20, then

```
DiscretePlot[P[n, .3], {n, 20}]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Use [`Manipulate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate.html) to explore the function as `p` and `n` varies.

```
Manipulate[
 DiscretePlot[P[n, p], {n, bigN}],
 {{p, 0.2}, .01, 1., .01},
 {{bigN, 20, "N"}, 1, 100, 1}
]
```

> [image]

Hope this helps.